# Is there a way to increase photon energy by decreasing its wavelength?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, photons, radiation

Can I decrease a photon's wavelength by a medium or a vacuum? Are there other ways of decreasing the wavelength?

Comment: Gravity.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment

Comment: Possibly Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13675/does-the-wavelength-always-decrease-in-a-medium?rq=1

Comment: There are non-linear optical processes like frequency doubling, but you don't get something for nothing (of course), you lose photon count in doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mention the basics for "other ways"', you can hit your photon really hard with a fast moving electron or proton, i.e. inverse Compton scattering.  ICS is very important in many astrophysical contexts. If you even reflect the photon off a moving mirror,  you can slightly increase or decrease its wavelength